# Replace array with another array by splice & push without touching non-unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

I have two arrays:

```
var current_items = [{hash: 1}, {hash: 2}, {hash: 3}];

var next_items    = [{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}];
```

The first array represents currently rendered items, the other represents the next items to render (simplified of course - the real objects contain a lot more information).

I need to replace the `current_items` array with the new items just by pushing/splicing. The problem is that I can not just override the `current_items` with the new items: **All current items that have the same hash as an item in `next_items` must be kept as they are** (if the object is changed/overridden the item would be rendered again unnecessarily).

I guess the first step would be to remove/splice all items in `current_items` that are not contained in next_items: current_items would become `[{hash: 3}]` (keep hash 3 because it is also contained in next_items).

Then remove all items from `next_items` that are already contained in `current_items`, so `next_items` becomes `[{hash: 4}, {hash: 5}]`

and finally concat the remaining `next_items` with the `current_items`

```
current_items.push.apply(current_items, next_items);
```

which results in `[{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}]`

My current solution looks something like this:

```
var current_items = [{hash: 1}, {hash: 2}, {hash: 3}];
var next_items    = [{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}];

// splice old items
var i = current_items.length, j, found;
while (i--) {
    found = false;
    for (j = 0; j < next_items.length; j++) {
        if (current_items[i]['hash'] === next_items[j]['hash']) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    !found && current_items.splice(i, 1);
}

// get unique new items
var unique_new_items = [];
for (i = 0; i < next_items.length; i++) {
    found = false;
    for (j = 0; j < current_items.length; j++) {
        if (next_items[i]['hash'] === current_items[j]['hash']) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    !found && unique_new_items.push(next_items[i]);
}

current_items.push.apply(current_items, unique_new_items); 
// [{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}]
```

Is there an easier/cleaner/shorter way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `Array.filter()`, `Array.concat()`, `Array.splice()`,`JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` functions:

```js
var current_items = [{hash: 1}, {hash: 2}, {hash: 3}],
    next_items    = [{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}],
    next_items_stringified = next_items.map(JSON.stringify);

current_items = current_items.filter(function (o) {
  var pos = this.indexOf(JSON.stringify(o));
  return pos !== -1 && this.splice(pos, 1);
}, next_items_stringified).concat(next_items_stringified.map(JSON.parse));

console.log(current_items);
```

Comment: you are aware that js doesn't guarantee property order so that filtering by `indexOf` && `JSON.stringify` might not always work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two hash table for the hashes and splice accordingly. Later push not included object to `current_items`.

```js
var current_items = [{ hash: 1 }, { hash: 2 }, { hash: 3, keep: true /* flag for identify this object */ }],
    next_items = [{ hash: 3 }, { hash: 4 }, { hash: 5 }],
    hashNext = Object.create(null),
    hashCurrent = Object.create(null);

next_items.forEach(function (a) {
    hashNext[a.hash] = true;
});

current_items.reduceRight(function (_, a, i, aa) {
    hashCurrent[a.hash] = true;
    if (!hashNext[a.hash]) {
        aa.splice(i, 1);
    }
}, 0);

next_items.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!hashCurrent[a.hash]) {
        current_items.push(a);
    }
});

console.log(current_items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might do as follows;

```js
var current_items = [{hash: 1}, {hash: 2}, {hash: 3}, {hash: 4}],
       next_items = [{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}, {hash: 6}],
           result = current_items.filter(h => next_items.some(g => g.hash === h.hash))
                                 .reduce((p,c,i,a) => i ? p.concat(next_items.filter(n => p.every(e => e.hash !== n.hash)))
                                                        : p.concat(a, next_items.filter(n => a.every(e => e.hash !== n.hash))),[]);
console.log(result);
```

And another explicit way of doing this job would be;

```js
var current_items = [{hash: 1}, {hash: 2}, {hash: 3}, {hash: 4}],
       next_items = [{hash: 3}, {hash: 4}, {hash: 5}, {hash: 6}],
            union = current_items.filter(c => next_items.some(n => c.hash === n.hash)),
       separation = next_items.filter(n => !union.some(u => n.hash === u.hash));
           result = union.concat(separation);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, as long as your arrays are sorted based on the hash (check twice, I'm not 100% sure that it works with every configuration).

```js
var curr = [{hash:1},{hash:2},{hash:3}];
var next = [{hash:3},{hash:4},{hash:5}];

var i = 0;
while (next.length > 0 || i < curr.length) {
  if (next.length == 0) {
    curr.pop();
  } else if (curr.length == i) {
    curr.push(next.shift()), i++;
  } else if (curr[i].hash > next[0].hash) {
    curr.splice(i++, 0, next.shift());
  } else if (curr[i].hash < next[0].hash) {
    curr.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    next.shift(), i++;
  }
}

console.log("[", curr.map(x => x.hash).join(" "), "]");
console.log("[", next.map(x => x.hash).join(" "), "]");
```

Though I would do something simpler :

```js
var curr = [{hash:1},{hash:2},{hash:3}];
var next = [{hash:3},{hash:4},{hash:5}];

function cookUpdate (curr, next) {
  var i = 0, j = 0, midd = [];
  while (j < next.length) {
    if (i == curr.length) {
      midd.push(next[j]), j++;
    } else if (curr[i].hash == next[j].hash) {
      midd.push(curr[i]), i++, j++;
    } else if (curr[i].hash > next[0].hash) {
      midd.push(next[j]), j++;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return midd;
}

curr = cookUpdate(curr, next);
next = [];

console.log("[", curr.map(x => x.hash).join(" "), "]");
console.log("[", next.map(x => x.hash).join(" "), "]");
```